# ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 9 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)

Tags: 18.04, kernel, freeze, acpi

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series.

Processor: AMD Ryzen 5.

```
7:29:44 PM kernel: ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 9 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)
7:29:44 PM kernel: ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 9 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)
7:29:44 PM kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, (SSDT:  D01WMI) while loading table (20170831/tbxfload-228)
7:29:44 PM kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
7:29:44 PM kernel: ACPI Error: [DGNS] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dswload-378)
```

Although my system is in working condition, however it randomly freeze at UI level, but the system level things are keep working with freeze UI. For example, if playback music, skype call and other background things keep working while the UI seems like freeze (Mouse, keyboard not working and hard reboot is only option.)

I have asked this question here to seek more help: [Ubuntu 18.04 is freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100230/ubuntu-18-04-is-freezing-randomly)

However, after trying many tweaks, found no success. So decided to solve each error logged at system level.

I would appreciate any help here.